# What ember.js component is responsible for inserting templates into the DOM?

Tags: dom, ember.js

I am building an ember.js/rails application.  All the handlebar templates are stored in .js files.  I'd like to understand how they get inserted into the DOM when the router changes state.  **Which part of ember does this?**  How do I tell ember to place templates?

Right now I can only get my templates appended to the `<body>` I have a [jsFiddle here](http://bit.ly/MItOcl).

I am aware of setting `rootElement` on Ember.Application, however I want the app to control other elements of the page.

**Handlebars / HTML**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h2>I'm the content</h2>
    <p>This should be inbetween the header &amp; footer</p>
    <p><strong>time</strong> {{time}}</p>
</script>

<header>
    <h1>Application</h1>
</header>
<article>
    <div id="content"></div>
</article>
<footer>
    <a href="http://blog.deanbrundage.com" target="_blank">by Dean</a>
</footer>
```

**​JavaScript**:

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    initialState: 'root.home',
    root: Em.Route.extend({
        home: Em.Route.extend({
            view: App.ApplicationView
        })
    })
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    time: Date()
});
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});

App.initialize();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current implementation in Ember.js appends the `ApplicationView` to the `rootElement` of the Application, see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/541d085ae039a190d24213d1476de53029355bf9/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L157-166).

One possible solution would be to overwrite the `appendTo` of your `ApplicationView`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/m8L6Z/:

**JavaScript**:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',
    appendTo: function(){
        this._super('#content');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  What I'm most interested in is the last solution (http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Yu3BX/) appending a view to an existing HTML page.  Can this be done with a `Router` or am I stuck putting my entire page into a handlebars template?

Comment: I've updated my answer since the stated information was not solving your problem.

Comment: if i only new this a day before.. now i wasted a day putting my entire site in handlebars :)

Comment: I like overriding `appendTo` since I'm going to have the application control other parts of the page.  Thanks for the help.  +50 for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using master, insertion and changing of templates is handled through outlets. 
Check out [the official guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/).

If you are using an older version of Ember, it's more of a manual process.

Comment: I understand outlets.  How do I get the **first** template into the DOM? Have a look at the jsFiddle.